# Find the inverse in $F = \frac{\Bbb{Z}_{7}[x]}{g(x)}$ of a polynomial $p(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse

$g(x) = x^{3}+2x^{2}+1$

$p(x) = x^{2}+x+2$

I don't know what I did wrong, hope you figured it out:

$g(x) = p(x)(x+1) + 4x + 6$

$p(x) = (4x+6)(2x+6)+1$

$1=p(x)-(2x+6)(4x+6)$

$1=p(x)-(2x+6)[g(x) - p(x)(x+1)]$

$1=p(x)+(5x+1)[g(x) + p(x)(6x+6)]$

$1=(5x+1)g(x) + 2(5x+1)(6x+6)p(x)]$

$1=(5x+1)g(x) + 2(2x^{2}+x+6)p(x)]$

$1=(5x+1)g(x) + (4x^{2}+2x+5)p(x)]$

So: my solution is $(4x^{2}+2x+5)$, but the text book report another result. Any suggestion?

Also: how can I say, without a doubt, that $F$ is a field?

Comment: In the sixth line, you go from $p(x) + (5x+1)[g(x)+p(x)(6x+6)]$ to $(5x+1)g(x) + 2(5x+1)(6x+6)p(x)$. But the number of factors of $p(x)$ that you have is $(5x+1)(6x+6)+1 = 2x^2+x$, not twice $(5x+1)(6x+6)$.

Comment: $F$ is a field since $g$ is irreducible (otherwise, as $\operatorname{deg} g=3$, it would have a linear factor and hence a root...).

Answer (score 1):

$F$ can be seen as the algebra generated by the matrix $M = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -2  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$( with entries in $GF(7)\; $), called the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial $g(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 + 1$. This matrix describes the action of the multiplication with $x$ namely $1 \mapsto x$, $x \mapsto x^2$ and $x^2 \mapsto x^3=-1-2x^2$. Then the polynomial $p(x)=x^2+x+2$ is represented by the matrix $N = M^2+M+2M^0 = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 4  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$. The inverse of $p$ is then represented by the inverse $N^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -2 & 3 \\
1 & 0 & 5 \\
2 & 4 & -1  \\
 \end{pmatrix} = 2M^2 + M $ (note that the coefficients of an element of the algebra in the basis $\{M^0, M, M^2\}$ always can be read from the first column) which corresponds to the polynomial $2x^2+x$.

Comment: If my calculations are right I get $p(x)(2x^2+x)  = g(x)(2x+3) + x^2+x+4$ but on the other hand $p(x)(x^2+4x+3)=g(x)(x+5)+1$.

Comment: OK, how can we do that?

Comment: I mistook $x^2 + 2x + 1$  for $x^2 + 2x^2 + 1$ ;-(, I'll rewrite my answer.